# Django Rest Framework @detail_route yields 404

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a `ViewSet` like

```
class CustomerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerSerializer
    filter_class = filters.CustomerFilterSet

    @detail_route
    def licenses(self, request, pk=None):
        customer = self.get_object()
        licenses = Item.objects.active().sold().for_customer(customer)
        serializer = serializers.ItemSerializer(licenses, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Strapped into `urls.py` with `router.register(r'customers', views.CustomerViewSet)`

i can `GET /api/customers` and `GET /api/customers/1000`, but `GET /api/customers/1000/licenses` is not found. It gives me `404`. The flow never enters the `licenses` method.

I looked at similar questions here, but they used an incorrect signature, which I do not: `def licenses(self, request, pk=None)`

```
python 3.4.0
djangorestframework==3.2.3
```

EDIT: Once again, I find my answer less than a minute after asking... Apparantly, the decorater needs parenthesees like `@detail_route()`. I thought these were always optional by convention..?

Comment: No there's no convention with parentheses. Decorator is in fact just callable which accepts function as its argument. So `detail_route` is function that returns callable.

Comment: I found an explanation detailing a way to double wrap a decorator like the one in my example so that both forms will be supported. Great to know that this is not a language convention but up to the developer

Answer (score 1):

For a `post` request you'll need to specify the method because the `detail_route` decorator will route `get` requests by default.
Like so: `@detail_route(methods=['POST'])`

Answer (score -2):

By default, router adds trailing slash to the url. So, `GET /api/customers/` would be working instead of `GET /api/customers`. If you don't want to use trailing slash you can pass `trailing_slash = False` to router initializer.

E.g.-

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash = False)
router.register(r'customers', views.CustomerViewSet)
```

If that does not works, then there is a problem with the way you are importing router urls into main urls.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question since both of your actions will work. `GET /api/customers` will just 301 to `GET /api/customers/`